# find value or prove limit doesn't exist.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given:

[image: equation]

[image: equation]

Find or prove it doesn't exist:

[image: equation]

....

My attempts thus far include:

I can show that [image: equation]   doesn't exist using  y=kx and showing path dependancy, but dunno if it's enough to prove that limg(x,y) doesn't exist.

(Don't know if lim h(x,y) not existing proves that lim h(x,y)*f(x,y) doesn't exist).

I think i can say that if  [image: equation]  than [image: equation] but can't find a use for it.

When using y=kx on lim g(x,y) i reach this point [image: equation],  but don't know what to say about it. (Don't know if f(x,y) is continuous at (0,0), does it even matter?)..

Would really appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: Just in case English isn't your first language, allow me to suggest that you *capitalize the first letter of each sentence*, *capitalize the first-person pronoun "I"*, and *NEVER USE "DUNNO" - instead, use "don't know" or "do not know"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Your last limit is wrong. It should be
$$\lim _{x\to 0} g(x,kx) = \frac{1-2k^2}{1+k^2}\cdot 5.$$

Comment: Is there a rule that allows you to use lim f(x,y)'s value at (0,0)? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: f need not have a value at (0,0). I am simply using the product rule for limits.

Comment: Doesn't lim h(x,y) have to exist in order to use the product rule on lim (h(x,y)*f(x,y)) ?

Comment: We are looking at h on the line y = kx. Along that line h has a limit.